# Count by combination

Tags: python, pandas, python-itertools

I have a dataset showing which cities each vehicle has been to (as shown in df1 below).

I'm trying to create a list of two-city combinations based on df1, and then for each two-city combination count how many vehicles have been to that particular two-city combination (like df2 below).

I dug around but couldn't find a solution. Does anyone have a solution for this?
(any help will be appreciated)

```
df1= pd.DataFrame([
[1,'A'],[1,'B'],[1,'C'],
[2,'A'],[2,'C'],[2,'C'],[2,'A'],
[3,'C'],[3,'B'],[3,'C'],[3,'B']],columns=['Vehicle_ID','City'])

df2= pd.DataFrame([['A,B',1],['B,C',2],['A,C',2]],
columns=['City_Combination','Vehicle_Count'])
```

Note:

(1) Order of cities visited doesn't matter. Eg. under the ('A,B') combination, vehicles that visited (A -> B) or (B -> A) or (A -> C -> B) will all be counted.

(2) Frequency of city visited doesn't matter. Eg. under the ('A,B') combination a vehicle that visited (A -> B -> A -> A) is still counted as 1 vehicle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two options. The first way is to group by the `Vehicle_ID` and for each group generate all the combinations of two cities. Collect the resulting city pairs and `Vehicle_ID` in a set of tuples (since we don't care about repeated city pairs) and then use the set to generate a new DataFrame. Then `groupby` the city pairs and count the distinct `Vehicle_ID`s:

```
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates()
data = set()
for vid, grp in df1.groupby(['Vehicle_ID']):
    for c1, c2 in IT.combinations(grp['City'], 2):
        if c1 > c2:
            c1, c2 = c2, c1
        data.add((c1, c2, vid))
df = pd.DataFrame(list(data), columns=['City_x', 'City_y', 'Vehicle_Count'])
#   City_x City_y  Vehicle_Count
# 0      B      C              3
# 1      A      C              1
# 2      B      C              1
# 3      A      C              2
# 4      A      B              1
result = df.groupby(['City_x', 'City_y']).count()
```

yields

```
               Vehicle_Count
City_x City_y               
A      B                   1
       C                   2
B      C                   2
```

---

An alternative way is to merge `df1` with itself:

```
In [244]: df1 = df1.drop_duplicates()

In [246]: df3 = pd.merge(df1, df1, on='Vehicle_ID', how='left'); df3
Out[246]: 
    Vehicle_ID City_x City_y
0            1      A      A
1            1      A      B
2            1      A      C
3            1      B      A
4            1      B      B
5            1      B      C
6            1      C      A
7            1      C      B
8            1      C      C
9            2      A      A
10           2      A      C
11           2      C      A
12           2      C      C
13           3      C      C
14           3      C      B
15           3      B      C
16           3      B      B
```

Unfortunately for us, `pd.merge` generates the direct product of city pairs, so 
we need to remove rows where `City_x >= City_y`:

```
In [247]: mask = df3['City_x'] < df3['City_y']
In [248]: df3 = df3.loc[mask]; df3
Out[249]: 
    Vehicle_ID City_x City_y
1            1      A      B
2            1      A      C
5            1      B      C
10           2      A      C
15           3      B      C
```

And now we can once again groupby `City_x`, `City_y` and count the result:

```
In [251]: result = df3.groupby(['City_x', 'City_y']).count(); result
Out[251]: 
               Vehicle_ID
City_x City_y            
A      B                1
       C                2
B      C                2
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools as IT

def using_iteration(df1):
    df1 = df1.drop_duplicates()
    data = set()
    for vid, grp in df1.groupby(['Vehicle_ID']):
        for c1, c2 in IT.combinations(grp['City'], 2):
            if c1 > c2:
                c1, c2 = c2, c1
            data.add((c1, c2, vid))
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(data), columns=['City_x', 'City_y', 'Vehicle_Count'])
    result = df.groupby(['City_x', 'City_y']).count()
    return result

def using_merge(df1):
    df1 = df1.drop_duplicates()
    df3 = pd.merge(df1, df1, on='Vehicle_ID', how='left')
    mask = df3['City_x'] < df3['City_y']
    df3 = df3.loc[mask]
    result = df3.groupby(['City_x', 'City_y']).count()
    result = result.rename(columns={'Vehicle_ID':'Vehicle_Count'})
    return result

def generate_df(nrows, nids, strlen):
    cities = (np.random.choice(list('ABCD'), nrows*strlen)
              .view('|S{}'.format(strlen)))
    ids = np.random.randint(nids, size=(nrows,))
    return pd.DataFrame({'Vehicle_ID':ids, 'City':cities})

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 'A'], [1, 'B'], [1, 'C'],
    [2, 'A'], [2, 'C'], [2, 'C'], [2, 'A'],
    [3, 'C'], [3, 'B'], [3, 'C'], [3, 'B']], columns=['Vehicle_ID', 'City'])

df = generate_df(10000, 50, 2)
assert using_merge(df).equals(using_iteration(df))
```

---

If `df1` is small, `using_iteration` may be faster than `using_merge`. For example, 
with the `df1` from the original post,

```
In [261]: %timeit using_iteration(df1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.45 ms per loop

In [262]: %timeit using_merge(df1)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.39 ms per loop
```

However, if we generate a DataFrame with 10000 rows and 50 `Vehicle_ID`s and 16 `City`s,
then `using_merge` may be faster than `using_iteration`:

```
df = generate_df(10000, 50, 2)

In [241]: %timeit using_merge(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.73 ms per loop

In [242]: %timeit using_iteration(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 16.3 ms per loop
```

Generally speaking, the more iterations required by the `for-loops` in
`using_iteration` -- i.e. the more `Vehicle_ID`s and possible city pairs -- the
more likely NumPy- or Pandas-based methods (such as `pd.merge`) will be faster.

Note however, that `pd.merge` generates a bigger DataFrame than we ultimately need. So `using_merge` may require more memory than `using_iteration`. So at some point, for sufficiently big `df1`s, `using_merge` may require swap space which can make `using_merge` slower than `using_iteration`.

So it is best to test `using_iteration` and `using_merge` (and other solutions) on your actual data to see what is fastest.

Comment: i like your suggestion about using `merge`, to your point about "big data" maybe this would be the approach to take if you were in a SQL as well (maybe SparkSQL or Redshift). just for your reference, you don't need `if c1 > c2`, since combinations will only return distinct "sets" of elements (see my answer), if you want all possible "tuples", you can use `itertools.permuations`

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions. Both merge and itertool work well. My df1 is quite large so as you predicted, merge runs faster. I do hope though there is way to do conditional merge (or join) as you could in SQL so I can say something like "where City_x < City_y" to make the joined table much smaller.

Answer (score 0):

First let's pivot the table so that the cities are columns, and there's one row per vehicle:

```
In [50]: df1['n'] = 1

In [51]: df = df1.pivot_table(index='Vehicle_ID', columns = 'City', values = 'n', aggfunc=sum)
         df
Out[51]:
City         A   B  C
Vehicle_ID
1            1   1  1
2            2 NaN  2
3          NaN   2  2
```

Now we can get the combinations with `itertools.combinations` (note we have to coerce to `list` to view all the values at once, since itertools  by default returns an iterator):

```
from itertools import combinations
city_combos = list(combinations(df1.City.unique(), 2))
city_combos
Out[19]: [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]
```

Finally we can iterate through the combos and compute the counts:

```
In [87]:     pd.Series({c:df[list(c)].notnull().all(axis=1).sum() for c in city_combos})
Out[87]:
A  B    1
   C    2
B  C    2
dtype: int64
```